# What kind of data is stored in google-services.json file (please discuss in detail)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know that what are the data stored in google-services.json file on firebase in brief and all the possible links and every kind of information are welcomed. It's just for getting to know about the json file in firebase and android. What I want is the details about the things present inside the google-services.json file

Comment: For Android, the contents are outlined here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase manages all of your API settings and credentials through a single configuration file.
The file is named google-services.json on Android and GoogleService-Info.plist on iOS.

GoogleService-Info.plist contains developer credentials and configuration settings, which is needed to verify while connecting with GoogleApiClient and also having a configuration for a different account like Analytics, Sign in, GCM  and also contain bundle id related to project.

Comment: What I want is the details about the things present inside the google-services.json file